# Read only for column in gridview

Tags: c#

I had Gridview bind sqldatasource  and I had logins which see gridview and I made roles for these logins som of them cannot see all gridview column so how can I make some columns read only .?

code
  public void CheckLoginAuthorty()
    {

```
    using (SqlConnection Con = Connection.GetConnection())
    {
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("CheackLoginInRole", Con);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        com.Parameters.Add(Parameter.NewNVarChar("@Login", Session.Contents["Username"].ToString()));
        object O = com.ExecuteScalar();

        if (O != null)
        {
            string S = O.ToString();

            if (IsInRole("AR-Translator", O.ToString()))
            {
            ///////// Grideview code/////////////////   
            }

            else if (IsInRole("EN-Translator", O.ToString()))
            {
       /////////Grideview code/////////////////   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want to hide some columns or just nor edit them?

Comment: I want to make specfic column read only according to role for user

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**EDIT:**

All you need to do is set the `ReadOnly` property to `true`

e.g.

**WinForms DataGridView**

```
dataGridView1.Columns["ColumnName"].ReadOnly = true;
```

**WebForms GridView**

```
((BoundField)gridView1.Columns[columnIndex]).ReadOnly = true;
```

Comment: ReadOnly property didnot find

Comment: Are you using a windows forms DataGridView or a web forms GridView?

Comment: Assuming its a BoundField use this:

((BoundField)gridView.Columns[intColumnIndex]).ReadOnly = true;

Comment: Are you sure they have values? Myabe try re-enabling them before you update?

Comment: Waht about itemtemplate columns? They do not have a readonly property.

Comment: @Dienekes: Have a read of this post http://forums.asp.net/t/1148251.aspx for disabling ItemTemplate columns

Answer (score 2):

```
 DataGridViewColumn column;
 column.ReadOnly = true;
```